# d3 line chart not smooth

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am building a chartfunction that transitions between a line chart, a grouped bar chart, and a stacked bar chart. The problem I am having is the line on the line chart does not look smooth.  I am not talking about the interpolate function I am referring to the actual physical line when it is plotted it looks jagged between points. Once the line reaches a point I am okay with a sharp turn. Its the diagonals that I have issue with.  I have used geometricPrecision on the path of the line. Below is the code I am using to generate the line and below the code is a JSFiddle.  I think it has to do with multiple lines being plotted but I can not see what would cause that in the code.

```
var svg = d3.select(chartname).select("svg").append("g").attr("class","l" + yValues)

    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate("linear") // linear, cardinal or monotone are good
        .x(function(d) {return xTime(d3.time.hour.offset(new Date(d.x),5))})
        .y(function(d) {return y(d.y)});

    var zeroline = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate("monotone") // linear, cardinal or monotone are good
        .x(function(d) {return xTime(d3.time.hour.offset(new Date(d.x),5))})
        .y(function(d) {return y(0)});
    // Add a title:
    svg.append("svg:text")
            .attr("x", width/4)
            .attr("y", 20)
            .attr("style", "font-size: 12; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif")
            .text("");


    svg.selectAll("g.yaxis").selectAll(".tick")
        .each(function(d) {
          if (d === 0) {
            this.remove();
          }
        });

    var activityLine = svg.selectAll(".activity")
        .data(inputdata[yValues])
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .attr("class", "activity");


       activityLine.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .transition("d")
        .delay(200)
        .attr("d", zeroline(inputdata[yValues]))
        .style("stroke", athenacolors[yValues])
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke-opacity", 0)
        .attr("stroke-width", .8)
        .attr("shape-rendering", "geometricPrecision");

      activityLine
        .append("circle")
        .style("cursor", "pointer")
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          d3.select(this).attr("r", "10")
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          d3.select(this).attr("r", 3.4)
        })
        .attr("stroke", function(d) {return athenacolors[yValues]; })
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
          return xTime(d3.time.hour.offset(new Date(d.x),5));
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
          return y(d.y);
        })
        .attr("stroke-width", 4.8)
        .attr("fill", "white")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.0001)
        .attr("fill-opacity", 0.0001)
        .transition("e").delay(200).duration(1500)
        .attr("stroke-opacity", 1)
        .attr("fill-opacity", 1)
        .attr("stroke-width", 3.8)
        .attr("r", 3.4);


svg.selectAll(".activity").selectAll("circle")
                .append("svg:title")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.y;
        })


svg.selectAll("path.line")
  .data(inputdata[yValues])
  .transition("f")
  .delay(500)
  .duration(100)
  .attr("stroke-opacity", 1)
  .attr("shape-rendering", "geometricPrecision")
  .transition()
  .delay(600)
  .duration(800)
  .attr("d", line(inputdata[yValues]))



d3.select(chartname).select("svg").selectAll("circle").style("opacity",1);
d3.select(chartname).select("svg").selectAll("circle").transition("cb").delay(400).duration(500).attr("r",10).transition("cb2").ease("bounce").delay(900).duration(500).attr("r",3.4);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bL1tu2ac/8/)

Comment: You already know what is happening: you have several lines with the same coordinates, because you have several groups. If you change `var activityLine = svg.selectAll(".activity").data(inputdata[yValues])` to `var activityLine = svg.selectAll(".activity").data(data)`, you'll see that the problem disappears (together with the circles!)

Comment: Thanks I made that change and it fixed the issue. The code is posted on JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/boarder7395/8dr9tuj0/ if anyone else had the same issue I did.